# Locating index of item via REGEX in Python

Tags: python, regex, search, loops, match

I've hit a wall and need some help.

Context: I have a list of lists of strings.

```
 Matrix = [['444'],
          ['23%'],
          ['A']]
```

For the moment, we have a list of Counts at position 0, Percentage at 1 and Significance test at 2.

The number of lists within the list changes from 3 to 2 to 1 from time to time. And the type of string within the list changes position. So I cannot assume that index 0 will always be Counts and percentage will be 1 etc.

Hence I wanted to find a way of dynamically finding out where percentage, for example, is located in the Matrix, and if its even in there.

Here is what I've written so far:

```
for i, row in enumerate(Matrix):
    for cell in row:
        if "%" in cell:
            percent = i
            print percent
for i, row in enumerate(Matrix):
    for cell in row:            
        if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', cell):
            sigtest = i
            print sigtest
for i, row in enumerate(Matrix):
    for cell in row:
        if re.search('[0-9]', cell):
            count = i
            print count
```

Output:

```
1
2
0
1
```

Problem: As you can see, the problem is located with the last for loop which records the fact that index 0 and 1 contain numbers.

Whats needed: A way for the last for loop to search for numbers and numbers only, a item contains numbers and a symbol, that index should not be included.

Hope that makes sense!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether the string contains only digits you can use :

```
>>> bool(re.search(r'^[0-9]+$', '4444'))
True
>>> '4444'.isdigit()    #Doesn't work for floats
True
# This will work for floats as well
>>> bool(re.search(r'^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?$', '4444.123'))
True
>>> bool(re.search(r'^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?$', '.123'))
True
```

For percentage you can use this `regex`

```
>>> bool(re.search(r'^[0-9]+%$', '23%'))
True
#To handle floats as well use this:
>>> bool(re.search(r'^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?%$', '23.15%'))
True
>>> bool(re.search(r'^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?%$', '.150%'))
True
```

For sigtest:

```
>>> bool(re.search(r'^[a-z]$', 'a',re.I))
True
>>> bool(re.search(r'^[a-z]$', 'B',re.I))
True
```

Here `^` and `$` are [meta-characters](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

`^` matches the start of the string and `$` matches the end of the string.

Comment: You only match unsigned number. You may start with  `(-|+)?`.

Comment: @ Ashwini, thanks for that. I tested it and the problem remains. If I want to find the index of a percentage string in the list (Matrix), your code will give me index 0 & 1 instead of 1 alone. I guess its because index 0 contains numbers too. Ideally, I want to run a single function to get the index of count, percent and significance.

Comment: @Boosted_d16 No it won't, for '444' my regex will return `False`. `bool(re.search(r'^[0-9]+%$', '444'))` --> `False`. You're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Ashwini, your correct. I dont know what I was doing wrong before but yes, it works. Thanks again!